# javascript function should switch between 2 images in a django template but doesn't

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a js function that should switch between 2 images when a button is clicked. This function worked fine switching images in an html page but when I used it inside a django project fails to change images in the template.

The initial situation was like this: the first image is displayed when the page is loaded, when the button is clicked it tries to change to the second images but fails to locate the source and gives a 404 error, a second click also fails to load the first image back;
so I fixed the path to the second image, now pressing the button once correctly load the second image but when clicked again fails to load the first image, pressing the button a third time correctly loads the second image tho, a step foward.

So I fixed the path to the first image (both images have the same path) and now clicking the button does nothing, the first images stands still.
the path is this: `ProjectName/AppName/static/AppName/dog1.jpg`

```html
{%load static%}
<img id="avatar" src="{% static 'AppName/dog1.jpg' %}" class="avatar">
<button id="Btn">Click me to change dogs<button>
```

```js
const dogs = [ "dog1.jpg", "/static/AppName/dog2.jpg" ];
const avatar = document.getElementById('avatar');
/*const dogs this way makes the function changeDog loads dog2.jpg perfectly every time is supposed to,
but fails to load back dog1.jpg; if I change
const dogs = [ "/static/AppName/dog1.jpg", "/static/AppName/dog2.jpg" ]
pressing the button do nothing and dog1.jpg is always displayed.*/

function changeDog() {
  const dog = avatar.src.split('/').slice(-1)[0];
/* I think the error may occours here split('/') */
  const index = dogs.indexOf( dog );
  console.log(dog)

  avatar.src = dogs[ ( index + 1 ) % dogs.length ];
  console.log( avatar.src );
}

var Btn = document.getElementById('Btn');
Btn.addEventListener('click', changeDog);
```

When `const dogs = [ "dog1.jpg", "/static/AppName/dog2.jpg" ];`

first click: everything fine

second click:

> dog1.jpg:1 GET htp://127.0.0.1:8000/AppName/dog1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

When `const dogs = [ "/static/AppName/dog1.jpg", "/static/AppName/dog2.jpg" ];`
clicking the button does nothing, no error in console, `dog1.jpg` stands still.

Any kind of help is really appreciated, hope to have made clear the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const index = dogs.indexOf("/static/AppName/" + dog );
```

I had to made an index including the relative path, not very intuitive but it worked.